# How to align asp:Labels in column?

Tags: asp.net, css, label, alignment

I have a one-column webpage. Within this fixed-width column I want to have 3 asp:Labels **on the same line**. The first Label must be left aligned, the center center aligned and the right label right aligned.

How do I mark up these asp:Labels to do what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the column is fixed width, wrap each label in a div with width explicitly set to 1/3 of the column. All 3 divs must float: left. Then use css to position the labels.

```
<div style="width: 300px">
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left; text-align: left">left</div>
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left; text-align: center">center</div>
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left; text-align: right">right</div>
</div>
```

Just replace the divs' content with your labels.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 1-row table as wide as your page and place each label within each cell. Set the align property on each cell to place the labels on left, center and right